# React image production src url issue

Tags: html, reactjs, react-router

I am a beginner in Reactjs, I created a login page and we are using a background image for the page.In localhost its working fine. After when we creating the project build and uploaded to the server then the login page image not working.(we required http://myIpaddress/abcd/static/media/bg-1.719367e0.jpg, but its showing like http://myIpaddress/static/media/bg-1.719367e0.jpg)

Comment: Looks like you need to set the right relative root path. Make sure your `homepage` property is properly set in the app's `package.json` file. See: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#building-for-relative-paths

Comment: Since you've tagged React Router as well, you'll want to make sure that the `basename` property is also properly set on your `<Router>`. See: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/BrowserRouter/basename-string